# Entendiendo el objeto lista en python

Tags: python, recursión

Quisiera entender este código de una función recursiva:

```py
def suma_recursiva(lista):
   if len(lista) == 1:
        return lista[0]
    else:
        return lista[0] + suma_recursiva(lista[1:])
print(suma_recursiva([1,3,5,7,9]))
```

Lo que no comprendo es justamente la parte recursiva de la función donde suma el primer item con la lista en rebanada de la misma. Es decir, si yo hago esto en el interprete de python esperaría que la variable resultado valiera 4; sumando el primer item con el segundo, sin embargo, al agregar los dos puntos para la forma de rebanado de lista me sale un error que dice que no se puede sumar un objeto entero con un objeto lista:

```py
l = [1,3,5,7,9]
a = l[0]
b = l[1:]
resultado = a + b
```

Me sale este error:

> Traeback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and
>   'list'

No obstante, en la función recursiva si lo hace, en la linea:

```
return lista[0] + suma_recursiva(lista[1:])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Listas y rebanadas

El operador `lista[1:]` te devuelve siempre *otra lista* y no el segundo elemento de la misma (para lo cual se usaría `lista[1]`). La lista devuelta por `lista[1:]` es la formada por el segundo elemento *y todos los siguientes*.

Es decir, si `lista=[1,2,3,4,5]`, entonces `lista[1:]` será `[2,3,4,5]`

No es de extrañar por tanto que `lista[0] + lista[1:]` te dé un error, pues estás intentando sumar un entero (`lista[0]`) con una lista, y la suma de esos tipos no está definida.

## Recursividad

Lo que hace la función recursiva no es sumar `lista[0]` más `lista[1:]`, sino que suma `lista[0]` con el *resultado* de aplicar la función `suma_recursiva()` a la sub-lista `lista[1:]`

Es decir, la filosofía detrás de esa implementación recursiva se expresaría así:

> La suma de una lista dada se calcula como:
>
> - Si la lista tiene un solo elemento, el valor de ese elemento
> - Si tiene más de uno, como la suma del primer elemento más *la suma de los restantes*.

Y la gracia de la recursividad es que, para calcular la suma de los restantes, llama a la propia función. A fin de cuentas ¿no tenemos una función para calcular la suma de una lista? ¿Por qué no usarla para que calcule la suma de una *sublista*?

Si te estás quedando perplejo sobre cómo es posible que funcione, es que estás empezando a descubrir las maravillas de la recursividad.

[image: Chiste]

## Cómo funciona

Lo mejor es que lo veas ejecutando "paso a paso" (o en tu cabeza) un ejemplo con tres elementos. La lista de entrada será por ejemplo `[1,2,3]`

- Comienza en el if. Ya que la lista no tiene 1 elemento, irá al `else`, y calculará la suma entre `1 + suma_recursiva([2,3])`

  - Vuelve a llamarse la misma función, ahora con una lista de dos elementos `[2,3]`. Ya que no tiene uno, entra por el `else` e intenta calcular `2 + suma_recursiva([3])`

    - Vuelve a llamarse la misma función, ahora con la lista `[3]`. Ya que tiene un solo elemento retorna su valor, `3`.
  - Así que `suma_recursiva([3])` devuelve 3, se le suma al 2 y se retorna 5.
- Así que `suma_recursiva([2,3])` vale 5, se le suma al 1 se retorna 6.

Y así ha calculado, casi como por magia, la suma de la lista completa.

## Advertencia

La recursividad es sorprendente y simplifica mucho algunos problemas. Pero es muy costosa. Si la lista tiene 100 elementos, se producirán 100 llamadas a funciones, y para cada llamada se crea una nueva sub-lista. Esto incurre en un gran costo en memoria y en tiempo de CPU. A partir de un cierto tamaño de la lista ni siquiera se podría calcular, pues se alcanzaría el máximo límite de llamadas anidadas de Python (cuál es este límite depende de la plataforma).

Cualquier función recursiva puede implementarse también de forma iterativa. En este caso la versión iterativa es trivial, y ni siquiera hace falta pues python tiene la función `sum(lista)`. En otros casos, pasar a la versión iterativa no es tan sencillo y el resultado puede ser más difícil de entender que la versión recursiva, pero siempre será más eficiente.